# Avoiding pdfbookmark with amsbook

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, hyperref, amsbook

I am using the [`amsbook`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsbook) class. I want a subsection with a title different from the ToC entry as in the example below

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\SkipTocEntry}[5]{} %modifica l'indice

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\SkipTocEntry}
\subsection{title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\tocsubsection{}{\thesubsection}{toc entry}}

\end{document}
```

However, this produces two pdfbookmarks, since both `\subsection` and `\addcontentsline` produce a pdfbookmark. What can I do to get rid of one of them?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you not use the "short title" optional argument of `\subsection`?

Comment: With amsbook the short title does not change the entry in the table of content, but only the entry in the page header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a not very known feature of the AMS classes:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Foo}
\section{\except{toc}{title}\for{toc}{toctitle}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

One can use the following predefined strings as the first argument of `\for` and `\except`:

- `runhead`
- `toc`
- `lof`
- `lot`