# Defining a chapter "outside" the last \part (amsbook)

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks, amsbook

Currently, I have the following:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\part{First Part}
\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\chapter{3}

\part{Second Part}
\chapter{4}
\chapter{5}

\chapter*{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

The table of contents is perfect. My only concern is how I see the contents in the side panel of my pdf viewer. Currently it shows:

```
Introduction
Part 1
  Chapter 1
  Chapter 2
  Chapter 3
Part 2
  Chapter 4
  Chapter 5
  Conclusion
```

whereas, what I wanted to have really is the following, where "Conclusion" is outside the last \part.

```
Introduction
Part 1
  Chapter 1
  Chapter 2
  Chapter 3
Part 2
  Chapter 4
  Chapter 5
Conclusion
```

Comment: It addresses not fully your needs, but it gives a clue how to avoid the 'wrong' bookmark. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109891/avoiding-pdfbookmark-with-amsbook -- by the way, with one of the standard classes, it would be much easier to correct the bookmark.

Comment: could you turn your snippets into a complete MWE that begins with `\documentclass...` and ends with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`bookmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) package:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\part{First Part}
\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\chapter{3}

\part{Second Part}
\chapter{4}
\chapter{5}

\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\chapter*{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

The bookmarks panel as displyed by Okular:

[image]

Comment: There's also usually some additional space at the end of a part in the table of contents. You might want to insert that manually as well to visually separate the Conclusion from Part 2: `\addtocontents{toc}{\bigskip}` (seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484703/2788450 )

Comment: I get `Option clash for package hyperref` trying this. I configure hyperref using `\usepackage[hidelinks, bookmarks=true, bookmarksopen=true,...]{hyperref}`. Any idea why and how to resolve this?

Comment: Ok, importing `bookmark` after `hyperref` resloves the error and does not seem to cause any other problems.